# Can I make do 'winecfg' in a custom location?

Tags: wine

Im a newbie and I have successfully installed wine. I want to make my fake C drive in my media folder instead of home folder(My home folder is very small size). Can I do that? If yes, Please how?  Also I want to know how would I be able to completely remove wine if I want to in the future?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can symlink you home extention for .wine directory.
To create a symlink to a new partition for for your wine data for example under /mmt/new_partition/ issue following command:

```
ln -s /home/<your username>/.wine /mnt/new_partition
```

More details on `ln` can be found by using:

```
ln --help
man ln
```

If you are not afraid off  recreating your wine settings you can remove all files from ~/.wine and `sudo mount -bind UUID /home/<your username>/.wine`.

Comment: Im curious what does symlink do? how do you do it?  Also to what extend would the given command remove wine(installed programs, config files etc) ?

Comment: you can only mount in a empty directory, so yes it will remove all your settings and already installed wine programs, but you can back it up before and restore it if you wish so. If you want to find out more about symlinking I suggest using `man 8 ln`. It is generealy a good idea to do a `-h` or `--help` the first time you are using a new comand. and reading the manpage(s).

Comment: I have enough time to wait for question by the OP owner and edit as neccary. if it is I can edit the comands in atm it was nessarcy yet as synlinkinghas multible aproaches to do. But if you have the right syntax at hand feel frre to edit my answer or create a own one.

Comment: Also the site chat is always a good oppotinity for such questions to get anwserd, but you need 20 rep on any SE site first.

Comment: Please someone im curios to know about how to make winecfg to make .wine folder in a custom directory,  like /media

Comment: Sorry, was on a other system for a moment but kirby is right I havene edited symlinks in yet.

Comment: Add added the missing instructions, hope you are satified yet @MarkKirby.

Comment: Can you not see how much of a better answer this is now? It is not about my satisfaction, it is about good answers and bad answers, answer questions in full, don't wait and see what the OP says, write your answers for anyone who may read it. Also please spellcheck your answers.

Comment: someone please answer my question Please. and yes that is a very valuable edit

Comment: ah, you added one `ln` to to the coded bits. I was not not sure if I should add it as code comant in float text there, but it is good so.

Comment: @buntul664 what edit did you made? I don't see any new changes yet.

Comment: @buntul664 This should answer your question. When you symlink the new dir to .wine, you can use the new dir as if it was .wine.

Comment: @Kupferdrache I did that just so it stands out and it is technically a command but it is up to you if want to do that.

Comment: @Kupferdrache you are being very helpful thanks for that. One thing I want to know is that wether I can somehow force wine to create .wine folder itself in some other desired directory. The reason why im wanna do this is only because i have only 1.5GB on home. I will learn how to increase that size some other day perhaps but I want solution to problem at hand Ie regarding .wine folder

Comment: No, as userspecific configuarion belong in that users home directory it is similar to the %appdata% in wines case, so it is importent to give it enough scape in the first place or you will have to handle a lot with 'mount` and the fstab file to make all the otherplaces mount where they are expectted to be by the programs. see Linux Standard Base (futher referred as LSB) and File System Hirarchie (FSH) if you want to find out more about how this thing work. Also, If you are satisfied with an answer don't forget to accenpt it, even it gets more expanded to show others that a question is solved.

Comment: Brother you seem to know very much about linux. Things have started to make sense to me now and the credit goes to you. Your answers are satsifying. I cant give upvote or accept(if that is some button that i dont know of) 'cause I dont have enough repo here. Also is there a pdf that you suggest that is a real qiuck guide on getting to know the terminal and file system side of linux(Ubuntu). Thanks

Comment: You are welcome, the button to accet an answer is the little tick below each answer, you can use it even you don't have the rep yet, the rep gets added once you got 15 rep you self. you can get it by infing an unansered question and answer it or by getting upvoted for your own questions. there is a whole tour about the rep system, may be you read ot if you find time for it.

Answer (score 0):

It's very easy to use different locations for your Wine directories. They're called Wine *prefixes*. If you do:

```
export WINEPREFIX=/some/path
winecfg
```

Then `winecfg` will use `/some/path` instead of `~/.wine`.

Having separate prefixes for the apps that you run under Wine is not only easy, but recommended, since different apps might require different (and possibly conflicting) tweaks.